# I am unable to configure the ADT plugin in eclipse 4.2.1 (on Mac OS X 10.5.8)

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing eclipse (and the android sdk) several times. I am trying to install the ADT plugin to develop an android app. After I download the ADT plugin and restart eclipse, I am unable to configure the plugin. The error log looks like this:

The error log says:

```
Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.lint
Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.avdManager
Unable to find Action SEt: adt.actionSet:refactorings
Unable to find Action SEt: adt.actionSet.wizards
System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|102...by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences.
```

I have read that I may have a problem with my workspace, however I'm pretty sure I had deleted everything pertaining to eclipse and the android sdk before I re-installed them. It seems like I can't get rid of my old workspace for some reason, although I'm not 100% sure that is the problem here.

I have been trying to figure this out for a week now with no luck. Thanks for the help!

Comment: excuse me, may I know the version of your eclipse-gef?

Comment: I never downloaded a gef individually. Is that is something that usually is included with eclipse 4.2.1? If so where can I look that up for you?  I downloaded eclipse classic here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Just deleted my old workspace and deleted Eclipse. Then I re-un-zipped the eclipse-sdk-4.2.1-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz on my Desktop. After installing the the ADT Plugin again, the error messages do not come up but the Android node still doesn't appear in the Preferences. I realize this is a popular topic and I feel like I have read every question and solution about this on the internet but to no avail. I'm not sure what else I can do. I also tried launching eclipse from x11 using "sudo ./eclipse" however that did not appear to help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Now, at this year (2013) you can try to download Android Studio, https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html